# innerHTML not getting called when using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

I have a bunch of paragraphs with a class name of "display". What I'm trying to do is get the the form input values (form is names "inputForm") and assign those to the paragraphs via innerHTML. The problem is that the for loop never executes.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
function displayFormInput() {
    var formElements = document.forms["inputForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
    for (var i; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].innerHTML += formElements[i].value;
        alert(i); // never gets called
    }
}
```

Comment: `var i = 0`.    ...

Comment: `undefined < number` is false

Comment: @Oriol. Thanks. Sometime I hate debugging javascript...

Comment: You would hate debugging less if you actually knew how to do it, such as stepping through your programmer with a debugger.

Comment: @torazaburo. I'm new to Javascript. I'm still learning.

Comment: Learning how to use devtools should be one of the very first things you learn. See the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `i` to ZERO within your for loop statements.

Try this instead for your for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].innerHTML += formElements[i].value;
   alert(i); // never gets called
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

In the loop's initialization expression, you are declaring the variable `i` without assigning it a value, which means that it's value is set to `undefined`. The loop's condition is therefore always false: `undefined < elements.length`, so the statement is never executed.

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

You fix this by declaring the variable and assigning it a value: `var i = 0`.